# Retrofit using two POJO class to parse JSON in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, retrofit, pojo

Hie, I am using the movie tmdb database to retrive data and the parsed json is as follows:

```
{  
   "page":1,
   "results":[  
      {  
         "adult":false,
         "backdrop_path":"/tbhdm8UJAb4ViCTsulYFL3lxMCd.jpg",
         "genre_ids":[  
            53,
            28,
            12
         ],
         "id":76341,
         "original_language":"en",
         "original_title":"Mad Max: Fury Road",
         "overview":"An apocalyptic story set in the furthest reaches of our planet, in a stark desert landscape where humanity is broken, and most everyone is crazed fighting for the necessities of life. Within this world exist two rebels on the run who just might be able to restore order. There's Max, a man of action and a man of few words, who seeks peace of mind following the loss of his wife and child in the aftermath of the chaos. And Furiosa, a woman of action and a woman who believes her path to survival may be achieved if she can make it across the desert back to her childhood homeland.",
         "release_date":"2015-05-15",
         "poster_path":"/kqjL17yufvn9OVLyXYpvtyrFfak.jpg",
         "popularity":51.773842,
         "title":"Mad Max: Fury Road",
         "video":false,
         "vote_average":7.8,
         "vote_count":1786
      },
      {  
         "adult":false,
         "backdrop_path":"/kvXLZqY0Ngl1XSw7EaMQO0C1CCj.jpg",
         "genre_ids":[  
            28,
            12,
            878
         ],
         "id":102899,
         "original_language":"en",
         "original_title":"Ant-Man",
         "overview":"Armed with the astonishing ability to shrink in scale but increase in strength, con-man Scott Lang must embrace his inner-hero and help his mentor, Dr. Hank Pym, protect the secret behind his spectacular Ant-Man suit from a new generation of towering threats. Against seemingly insurmountable obstacles, Pym and Lang must plan and pull off a heist that will save the world.",
         "release_date":"2015-07-17",
         "poster_path":"/7SGGUiTE6oc2fh9MjIk5M00dsQd.jpg",
         "popularity":44.138852,
         "title":"Ant-Man",
         "video":false,
         "vote_average":7.1,
         "vote_count":946
      },
      {  
         "adult":false,
         "backdrop_path":"/bIlYH4l2AyYvEysmS2AOfjO7Dn8.jpg",
         "genre_ids":[  
            878,
            28,
            53,
            12
         ],
         "id":87101,
         "original_language":"en",
         "original_title":"Terminator Genisys",
         "overview":"The year is 2029. John Connor, leader of the resistance continues the war against the machines. At the Los Angeles offensive, John's fears of the unknown future begin to emerge when TECOM spies reveal a new plot by SkyNet that will attack him from both fronts; past and future, and will ultimately change warfare forever.",
         "release_date":"2015-07-01",
         "poster_path":"/5JU9ytZJyR3zmClGmVm9q4Geqbd.jpg",
         "popularity":37.160125,
         "title":"Terminator Genisys",
         "video":false,
         "vote_average":6.3,
         "vote_count":781
      },
      {  
         "adult":false,
         "backdrop_path":"/dmnaqPsvJuBSoDtbd8BkDZzPGzi.jpg",
         "genre_ids":[  
            35
         ],
         "id":116741,
         "original_language":"en",
         "original_title":"The Internship",
         "overview":"Two recently laid-off men in their 40s try to make it as interns at a successful Internet company where their managers are in their 20s.",
         "release_date":"2013-06-07",
         "poster_path":"/xxOKDTQbQo7h1h7TyrQIW7u8KcJ.jpg",
         "popularity":31.049928,
         "title":"The Internship",
         "video":false,
         "vote_average":6.1,
         "vote_count":705
      },
      {  
         "adult":false,
         "backdrop_path":"/t5KONotASgVKq4N19RyhIthWOPG.jpg",
         "genre_ids":[  
            28,
            12,
            878,
            53
         ],
         "id":135397,
         "original_language":"en",
         "original_title":"Jurassic World",
         "overview":"Twenty-two years after the events of Jurassic Park, Isla Nublar now features a fully functioning dinosaur theme park, Jurassic World, as originally envisioned by John Hammond.",
         "release_date":"2015-06-12",
         "poster_path":"/uXZYawqUsChGSj54wcuBtEdUJbh.jpg",
         "popularity":26.753134,
         "title":"Jurassic World",
         "video":false,
         "vote_average":7.0,
         "vote_count":1950
      },
      {  
         "adult":false,
         "backdrop_path":"/L5QRL1O3fGs2hH1LbtYyVl8Tce.jpg",
         "genre_ids":[  
            53,
            28,
            878,
            10749
         ],
         "id":262500,
         "original_language":"en",
         "original_title":"Insurgent",
         "overview":"Beatrice Prior must confront her inner demons and continue her fight against a powerful alliance which threatens to tear her society apart.",
         "release_date":"2015-03-20",
         "poster_path":"/aBBQSC8ZECGn6Wh92gKDOakSC8p.jpg",
         "popularity":25.195584,
         "title":"Insurgent",
         "video":false,
         "vote_average":6.9,
         "vote_count":933
      },
      {  
         "adult":false,
         "backdrop_path":"/sLbXneTErDvS3HIjqRWQJPiZ4Ci.jpg",
         "genre_ids":[  
            10751,
            16,
            12,
            35
         ],
         "id":211672,
         "original_language":"en",
         "original_title":"Minions",
         "overview":"Minions Stuart, Kevin and Bob are recruited by Scarlet Overkill, a super-villain who, alongside her inventor husband Herb, hatches a plot to take over the world.",
         "release_date":"2015-06-25",
         "poster_path":"/s5uMY8ooGRZOL0oe4sIvnlTsYQO.jpg",
         "popularity":24.605627,
         "title":"Minions",
         "video":false,
         "vote_average":6.9,
         "vote_count":993
      },
      {  
         "adult":false,
         "backdrop_path":"/uHeMMJIZRVjeS2WIFcxBCdCTdmk.jpg",
         "genre_ids":[  
            28,
            12,
            53
         ],
         "id":177677,
         "original_language":"en",
         "original_title":"Mission: Impossible – Rogue Nation",
         "overview":"Ethan and team take on their most impossible mission yet, eradicating the Syndicate - an International rogue organization as highly skilled as they are, committed to destroying the IMF.",
         "release_date":"2015-07-31",
         "poster_path":"/6PgpI2Uj4s1solkGWaYXP5QgO1I.jpg",
         "popularity":24.128192,
         "title":"Mission: Impossible – Rogue Nation",
         "video":false,
         "vote_average":7.2,
         "vote_count":515
      },
      {  
         "adult":false,
         "backdrop_path":"/nkwoiSVJLeK0NI8kTqioBna61bm.jpg",
         "genre_ids":[  
            35
         ],
         "id":214756,
         "original_language":"en",
         "original_title":"Ted 2",
         "overview":"Newlywed couple Ted and Tami-Lynn want to have a baby, but in order to qualify to be a parent, Ted will have to prove he's a person in a court of law.",
         "release_date":"2015-06-26",
         "poster_path":"/A7HtCxFe7Ms8H7e7o2zawppbuDT.jpg",
         "popularity":20.634718,
         "title":"Ted 2",
         "video":false,
         "vote_average":6.9,
         "vote_count":576
      },
      {  
         "adult":false,
         "backdrop_path":"/aUYcExsGuRaw7PLGmAmXubt1dfG.jpg",
         "genre_ids":[  
            10749,
            14,
            10751,
            18
         ],
         "id":150689,
         "original_language":"en",
         "original_title":"Cinderella",
         "overview":"When her father unexpectedly passes away, young Ella finds herself at the mercy of her cruel stepmother and her daughters. Never one to give up hope, Ella's fortunes begin to change after meeting a dashing stranger in the woods.",
         "release_date":"2015-03-13",
         "poster_path":"/2i0JH5WqYFqki7WDhUW56Sg0obh.jpg",
         "popularity":18.480602,
         "title":"Cinderella",
         "video":false,
         "vote_average":7.0,
         "vote_count":558
      },
      {  
         "adult":false,
         "backdrop_path":"/lyVlbE8iRIdGBUwhq79EziqHSBW.jpg",
         "genre_ids":[  
            28,
            12,
            878
         ],
         "id":166424,
         "original_language":"en",
         "original_title":"Fantastic Four",
         "overview":"Four young scientists teleport to an alternate and dangerous universe, which alters their physical form in shocking ways. They must now use these abilities to save the world from a former friend turned enemy.",
         "release_date":"2015-08-07",
         "poster_path":"/g23cs30dCMiG4ldaoVNP1ucjs6.jpg",
         "popularity":17.614168,
         "title":"Fantastic Four",
         "video":false,
         "vote_average":4.9,
         "vote_count":271
      },
      {  
         "adult":false,
         "backdrop_path":"/2BXd0t9JdVqCp9sKf6kzMkr7QjB.jpg",
         "genre_ids":[  
            12,
            10751,
            16,
            28,
            35
         ],
         "id":177572,
         "original_language":"en",
         "original_title":"Big Hero 6",
         "overview":"The special bond that develops between plus-sized inflatable robot Baymax, and prodigy Hiro Hamada, who team up with a group of friends to form a band of high-tech heroes.",
         "release_date":"2014-11-07",
         "poster_path":"/3zQvuSAUdC3mrx9vnSEpkFX0968.jpg",
         "popularity":17.35535,
         "title":"Big Hero 6",
         "video":false,
         "vote_average":7.9,
         "vote_count":2084
      },
      {  
         "adult":false,
         "backdrop_path":"/xu9zaAevzQ5nnrsXN6JcahLnG4i.jpg",
         "genre_ids":[  
            18,
            878
         ],
         "id":157336,
         "original_language":"en",
         "original_title":"Interstellar",
         "overview":"Interstellar chronicles the adventures of a group of explorers who make use of a newly discovered wormhole to surpass the limitations on human space travel and conquer the vast distances involved in an interstellar voyage.",
         "release_date":"2014-11-05",
         "poster_path":"/nBNZadXqJSdt05SHLqgT0HuC5Gm.jpg",
         "popularity":16.96893,
         "title":"Interstellar",
         "video":false,
         "vote_average":8.4,
         "vote_count":3108
      },
      {  
         "adult":false,
         "backdrop_path":"/fii9tPZTpy75qOCJBulWOb0ifGp.jpg",
         "genre_ids":[  
            36,
            18,
            53,
            10752
         ],
         "id":205596,
         "original_language":"en",
         "original_title":"The Imitation Game",
         "overview":"Based on the real life story of legendary cryptanalyst Alan Turing, the film portrays the nail-biting race against time by Turing and his brilliant team of code-breakers at Britain's top-secret Government Code and Cypher School at Bletchley Park, during the darkest days of World War II.",
         "release_date":"2014-11-14",
         "poster_path":"/noUp0XOqIcmgefRnRZa1nhtRvWO.jpg",
         "popularity":15.565414,
         "title":"The Imitation Game",
         "video":false,
         "vote_average":8.1,
         "vote_count":1706
      },
      {  
         "adult":false,
         "backdrop_path":"/qhH3GyIfAnGv1pjdV3mw03qAilg.jpg",
         "genre_ids":[  
            12,
            14
         ],
         "id":122917,
         "original_language":"en",
         "original_title":"The Hobbit: The Battle of the Five Armies",
         "overview":"Mere seconds after the events of \"Desolation\", Bilbo and Company continue to claim a mountain of treasure that was guarded long ago: But with Gandalf the Grey also facing some formidable foes of his own, the Hobbit is outmatched when the brutal army of orcs led by Azog the Defiler returns. But with other armies such as the elves and the men of Lake-Town, which are unsure to be trusted, are put to the ultimate test when Smaug's wrath, Azog's sheer strength, and Sauron's force of complete ends attack. All in all, the trusted armies have two choices: unite or die. But even worse, Bilbo gets put on a knife edge and finds himself fighting with Hobbit warfare with all of his might for his dwarf-friends, as the hope for Middle-Earth is all put in Bilbo's hands. The one \"precious\" thing to end it all.",
         "release_date":"2014-12-17",
         "poster_path":"/qrFwjJ5nvFnpBCmXLI4YoeHJNBH.jpg",
         "popularity":15.370585,
         "title":"The Hobbit: The Battle of the Five Armies",
         "video":false,
         "vote_average":7.2,
         "vote_count":1788
      },
      {  
         "adult":false,
         "backdrop_path":"/nvZVu6inpwLHKqRXZhye3S4uqei.jpg",
         "genre_ids":[  
            28,
            35,
            878
         ],
         "id":257344,
         "original_language":"en",
         "original_title":"Pixels",
         "overview":"Video game experts are recruited by the military to fight 1980s-era video game characters who've attacked New York.",
         "release_date":"2015-07-24",
         "poster_path":"/ktyVmIqfoaJ8w0gDSZyjhhOPpD6.jpg",
         "popularity":14.724169,
         "title":"Pixels",
         "video":false,
         "vote_average":6.4,
         "vote_count":253
      },
      {  
         "adult":false,
         "backdrop_path":"/bHarw8xrmQeqf3t8HpuMY7zoK4x.jpg",
         "genre_ids":[  
            878,
            14,
            12
         ],
         "id":118340,
         "original_language":"en",
         "original_title":"Guardians of the Galaxy",
         "overview":"Light years from Earth, 26 years after being abducted, Peter Quill finds himself the prime target of a manhunt after discovering an orb wanted by Ronan the Accuser.",
         "release_date":"2014-08-01",
         "poster_path":"/9gm3lL8JMTTmc3W4BmNMCuRLdL8.jpg",
         "popularity":14.551749,
         "title":"Guardians of the Galaxy",
         "video":false,
         "vote_average":8.1,
         "vote_count":3255
      },
      {  
         "adult":false,
         "backdrop_path":"/pfyWJUxrBTT2UIPoEQF3iFTHcQT.jpg",
         "genre_ids":[  
            80,
            35,
            28,
            12
         ],
         "id":207703,
         "original_language":"en",
         "original_title":"Kingsman: The Secret Service",
         "overview":"Kingsman: The Secret Service tells the story of a super-secret spy organization that recruits an unrefined but promising street kid into the agency's ultra-competitive training program just as a global threat emerges from a twisted tech genius.",
         "release_date":"2015-02-13",
         "poster_path":"/8x7ej0LnHdKUqilNNJXYOeyB6L9.jpg",
         "popularity":14.532191,
         "title":"Kingsman: The Secret Service",
         "video":false,
         "vote_average":7.7,
         "vote_count":1832
      },
      {  
         "adult":false,
         "backdrop_path":"/anItUS64TeGKPv6MJ99DMv7o0Z0.jpg",
         "genre_ids":[  
            35,
            10402
         ],
         "id":254470,
         "original_language":"en",
         "original_title":"Pitch Perfect 2",
         "overview":"The Bellas are back, and they are better than ever. After being humiliated in front of none other than the President of the United States of America, the Bellas are taken out of the Aca-Circuit. In order to clear their name, and regain their status, the Bellas take on a seemingly impossible task: winning an international competition no American team has ever won. In order to accomplish this monumental task, they need to strengthen the bonds of friendship and sisterhood and blow away the competition with their amazing aca-magic! With all new friends and old rivals tagging along for the trip, the Bellas can hopefully accomplish their dreams.",
         "release_date":"2015-05-15",
         "poster_path":"/qSjruLiFB4uqRtz2xheQPxG8uaB.jpg",
         "popularity":13.765999,
         "title":"Pitch Perfect 2",
         "video":false,
         "vote_average":7.1,
         "vote_count":450
      },
      {  
         "adult":false,
         "backdrop_path":"/A0bFdUMtd4mcXMRou7alzk6HQVZ.jpg",
         "genre_ids":[  
            35,
            28,
            12
         ],
         "id":203801,
         "original_language":"en",
         "original_title":"The Man from U.N.C.L.E.",
         "overview":"In the early 1960s, CIA agent Napoleon Solo and KGB operative Illya Kuryakin participate in a joint mission against a mysterious criminal organization, which is working to proliferate nuclear weapons.",
         "release_date":"2015-08-14",
         "poster_path":"/5ttOaThDVmTpV8iragbrhdfxEep.jpg",
         "popularity":13.33388,
         "title":"The Man from U.N.C.L.E.",
         "video":false,
         "vote_average":5.9,
         "vote_count":83
      }
   ],
   "total_pages":11963,
   "total_results":239260
}
```

And the POJO for the above is as follows:

The Fist one generated is as follows

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
public class Example {

@Expose
private Integer page;
@Expose
private List<Result> results = new ArrayList<Result>();
@SerializedName("total_pages")
@Expose
private Integer totalPages;
@SerializedName("total_results")
@Expose
private Integer totalResults;

/**
* 
* @return
* The page
*/
public Integer getPage() {
return page;
}

/**
* 
* @param page
* The page
*/
public void setPage(Integer page) {
this.page = page;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The results
*/
public List<Result> getResults() {
return results;
}

/**
* 
* @param results
* The results
*/
public void setResults(List<Result> results) {
this.results = results;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The totalPages
*/
public Integer getTotalPages() {
return totalPages;
}

/**
* 
* @param totalPages
* The total_pages
*/
public void setTotalPages(Integer totalPages) {
this.totalPages = totalPages;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The totalResults
*/
public Integer getTotalResults() {
return totalResults;
}

/**
* 
* @param totalResults
* The total_results
*/
public void setTotalResults(Integer totalResults) {
this.totalResults = totalResults;
}

}
```

The second one is as follows:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
public class Result {

@Expose
private Boolean adult;
@SerializedName("backdrop_path")
@Expose
private String backdropPath;
@SerializedName("genre_ids")
@Expose
private List<Integer> genreIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
@Expose
private Integer id;
@SerializedName("original_language")
@Expose
private String originalLanguage;
@SerializedName("original_title")
@Expose
private String originalTitle;
@Expose
private String overview;
@SerializedName("release_date")
@Expose
private String releaseDate;
@SerializedName("poster_path")
@Expose
private String posterPath;
@Expose
private Double popularity;
@Expose
private String title;
@Expose
private Boolean video;
@SerializedName("vote_average")
@Expose
private Double voteAverage;
@SerializedName("vote_count")
@Expose
private Integer voteCount;

/**
* 
* @return
* The adult
*/
public Boolean getAdult() {
return adult;
}

/**
* 
* @param adult
* The adult
*/
public void setAdult(Boolean adult) {
this.adult = adult;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The backdropPath
*/
public String getBackdropPath() {
return backdropPath;
}

/**
* 
* @param backdropPath
* The backdrop_path
*/
public void setBackdropPath(String backdropPath) {
this.backdropPath = backdropPath;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The genreIds
*/
public List<Integer> getGenreIds() {
return genreIds;
}

/**
* 
* @param genreIds
* The genre_ids
*/
public void setGenreIds(List<Integer> genreIds) {
this.genreIds = genreIds;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The id
*/
public Integer getId() {
return id;
}

/**
* 
* @param id
* The id
*/
public void setId(Integer id) {
this.id = id;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The originalLanguage
*/
public String getOriginalLanguage() {
return originalLanguage;
}

/**
* 
* @param originalLanguage
* The original_language
*/
public void setOriginalLanguage(String originalLanguage) {
this.originalLanguage = originalLanguage;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The originalTitle
*/
public String getOriginalTitle() {
return originalTitle;
}

/**
* 
* @param originalTitle
* The original_title
*/
public void setOriginalTitle(String originalTitle) {
this.originalTitle = originalTitle;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The overview
*/
public String getOverview() {
return overview;
}

/**
* 
* @param overview
* The overview
*/
public void setOverview(String overview) {
this.overview = overview;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The releaseDate
*/
public String getReleaseDate() {
return releaseDate;
}

/**
* 
* @param releaseDate
* The release_date
*/
public void setReleaseDate(String releaseDate) {
this.releaseDate = releaseDate;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The posterPath
*/
public String getPosterPath() {
return posterPath;
}

/**
* 
* @param posterPath
* The poster_path
*/
public void setPosterPath(String posterPath) {
this.posterPath = posterPath;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The popularity
*/
public Double getPopularity() {
return popularity;
}

/**
* 
* @param popularity
* The popularity
*/
public void setPopularity(Double popularity) {
this.popularity = popularity;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The title
*/
public String getTitle() {
return title;
}

/**
* 
* @param title
* The title
*/
public void setTitle(String title) {
this.title = title;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The video
*/
public Boolean getVideo() {
return video;
}

/**
* 
* @param video
* The video
*/
public void setVideo(Boolean video) {
this.video = video;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The voteAverage
*/
public Double getVoteAverage() {
return voteAverage;
}

/**
* 
* @param voteAverage
* The vote_average
*/
public void setVoteAverage(Double voteAverage) {
this.voteAverage = voteAverage;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The voteCount
*/
public Integer getVoteCount() {
return voteCount;
}

/**
* 
* @param voteCount
* The vote_count
*/
public void setVoteCount(Integer voteCount) {
this.voteCount = voteCount;
}
```

Now how do I use retrofit to parse the data also how to use recycler view for the above.

Comment: Have you written any retrofit-related code? There's is the documentation that tells you how to do what you want http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Comment: Yes I have but I am not able to do that for two model class.

Answer (score 0):

Retrofit takes care of the parsing, you don't need to handle "2 POJOS", retrofit uses your main POJO which is the `Example` class:

```
public interface  YourService {

    @GET("/path/to/your/rest/api")
    void yourJSONRequest(Callback<Example> callback);
}
```

And your call should be something like:

```
yourJSONRequest(new Callback<Example>() {
    @Override
    public void success(Example example, Response response) {
        // Do whatever you want
        for(Result result : example.getResults()){
            // Here is your result
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
      // Error handling
    }
});
```

Comment: then how to obtain the values from the Result class?

Comment: But i want to get data from the server, not POST it so is it fine if i change the @POST with @GET?

Comment: Oh, sorry...my bad. Yes, you need to change to @GET.

Comment: how to get the getters in the adapter in the getView method?

Comment: Mmm...that should be another question. Are you getting the data in the success method?

Comment: No, i am not able to get it

Comment: Dude, is hard to know what's going on without any error messages or log info.